# Batch script to move the files from source to destination based on the file name

Tags: batch-file

The detail requirement is I need to move files from source folder to Destination folder based on the File names. For example

`ABC_TEST1.txt` should be moved to `Y:\Dest\ABC`, `EFG_TEST1.txt` should be moved to `Y:\Dest\EFG`, `XYZ.txt` should be moved to `Y:\Dest\Unkonow`, `GHI_TEST1.txt` should be moved to `Y:\Dest\Unkown`.

I tried the script below.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (*.txt) do ( 
    set FileName=%%F
    echo %%F
    if x%FileName:_=%==x%FileName%(
        for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%B in ("%%~nXF") do (
            ren "%%F" "%%C"
            if exist "Y:\Dest\%%B" (move "%%C" "Y:\Dest\%%B")   else (move "%%C" "Y:\Dest\Unknown")
        )
    )else (move "%%C" "Y:\Dest\Unknown")
        
)
endlocal
```

If I add the if condition the script is not working, without the if condition it's working.

`ABC_TEST1.txt` should be moved to `Y:\Dest\ABC`, `EFG_TEST1.txt` should be moved to `Y:\Dest\EFG`

It's not moving the `XYZ.txt`, `GHI_TEST1.txt` to `Y:\Dest\Unkonow`.

Comment: You have enabled delayed expansion, but are not using it. Also there should always be a space in front of an opening parenthesis which does not begin a command. ```if x%FileName:_=%==x%FileName%(``` needs to be ```if x!FileName:_=!==x!FileName! (``` and ahould preferably be ```if "!FileName:_=!" == "!FileName!" (```.